# How do I fix my globbing syntax when using grep -v and shell_exec

Tags: php, grep, trim, shell-exec, glob

I want to list files that match a certain pattern: `Name (Europe)`, but also DOES NOT contain the pattern: `(??,` < AKA an open bracket, two characters which could be anything and a comma - For example `(En,`.

I am having to use shell_exec as the script is going through all sorts of files with funny characters. So far I have:

```
$fCheck = trim(shell_exec("ls -1 \"{$niceName} (Europe)\"* 2>/dev/null | grep -v '(??,'"));
```

But I think the globbing syntax is wrong? That or the `shell_exec` is messing it up somehow. Apologies for my lack of knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

`grep -v '([A-Z][a-z],'` seems to be working!